# not able to insert values in table ,giving error ,column count doesn't match

Tags: mysql

Schedule table has five columns gameday,oppoent,scoredifference,score,opponent score .
scoredifference is generated column.
I m trying to insert into schedule table, its giving me error#1136;

```
insert into schedule values('2017-02-01','atlanta falcons',14,7);
```

Comment: bad way of insert. better you got the error now. think if for some reason the last 2 column orders get changed?

Comment: I would suggest typing the column names always in SELECT, INSERT or UPDATE. a little bit of typing now while you still remember the column names, can save you from a lot of nightmares later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be trying to insert values into a computed column.  Rather, this column will be computed on the fly when you actually query your table.  Instead, try specifying the four column names whose data you are trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO schedule (gameday, opponent, scoredifference, score)
VALUES
    ('2017-02-01', 'atlanta falcons', 14, 7);
```

But ... your values part contains 4 columns so match all fields.

Comment: Thanks Tim for correction while @Kavita said that table contains 5 columns

Comment: also make sure that any other columns other than the four named in the query, either allow `null`s or have a default value or is auto increment.

Comment: @kavita : you welcome. You can mark answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

insert into tablename (column-list) values(value-list) , you need to specify the column-list if you are not inserting for all columns or not in order.

Answer (score 0):

Please set default value of scoredifference column as 0 (or whatever you want), and try following query :

```
insert into schedule(gameday,oppoent,score,opponentscore) values('2017-02-01','atlanta falcons',14,7);
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think ScoreDifference is not primary key therefore not auto increment. You can use this;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [Scoredifference] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Gameday] [datetime] NULL,
    [Oppoent] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Score] [int] NULL,
    [OpponentScore] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Scoredifference] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then insert this;

insert into schedule values('2017-02-01','atlanta falcons',14,7);

Answer (score 0):

Your column doesn't match with your table. And it is a bad haabit to use insert query. Just Checkout this :

**1. Use Column Name Before Values You Want To Insert**

```
insert into schedule(date,city,t1,t2) values ('2017-02-01','atlanta falcons',14,7);
```

**2. Match The Column Properly. But This is Not The Proper Way to Insert.**

```
insert into schedule values ('','2017-02-01','atlanta falcons',14,7);
```